# How can I import my .txt data to a dataframe if my rows doesn't have the same cols number?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

**Context**:

I have a .txt that contains some data.

My data is like this:

```
|field1|field2|field3|field4|field5|:
|field1|field2|field3|field4|
|field1|field2|field3|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|field5|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|
```

The value of the field can be a number or a string,
and my file doesn't respect a defined pattern...

The rows aren't like "ABCABCABC..." they're more like "AMASOAUSAHA"

I need to find a way to import my data to a `.dataframe()` in such a way that I can get a value from a field from `(row[i], col[j])` and work to replace it in `(row[k], col[l])`.

**Question**:

> I have a file that doesn't have the same number of cols, but respects
>   the use of the same separator over the rows. So, is there any way to
>   import my data to a dataframe if my rows doesn't have the same cols
>   number?

Comment: "over the months"? That is really unclear, since there was no reference made to months. Maybe you should consider referring only to things that exist in the example you have provided. If the example isn't similar enough to your use case, improve the example. Similarly, I don't see why we need to know that you have "5fields" while your example has "5 fields" -- just make a good example and refer to it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, fill = T, sep = "|", text = "
|field1|field2|field3|field4|field5|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|
|field1|field2|field3|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|field5|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|
|field1|field2|field3|field4|")
df[2, 2] <- "foo"
df
#   V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6 V7
# 1 NA field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 NA
# 2 NA    foo field2 field3 field4        NA
# 3 NA field1 field2 field3               NA
# 4 NA field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 NA
# 5 NA field1 field2 field3 field4        NA
# 6 NA field1 field2 field3 field4        NA
```

... in R (which you tagged).

Comment: guess i haven't understood what `?read.table` told me.. heheh. thanks luke!

Answer (score 1):

Using Python, if `data` looks like

```
field1|field2|field3|field4
field1|field2|field3
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2|field3|field4
field1|field2|field3|field4
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame((row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='|'))).fillna('')
    df.iloc[1, 1] = 'foo'
    print(df)
```

yields

```
        0       1       2       3       4
0  field1  field2  field3  field4        
1  field1     foo  field3                
2  field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
3  field1  field2  field3  field4        
4  field1  field2  field3  field4
```